# How to edit the Issue tracking list columns for my Create & Edit views

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, issue-tracking

I have added an issue tracking list App inside my SharePoint 2013. And I was able to edit the columns (hide column, change order) for my All items, my items , etc views. But there is no option for example to change the order or to hide certain columns from my Edit & Create views. So can anyone advice on this please ?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going into the List Settings -> Advanced Settings and check the box to manage content types.  You should then be able to click on the content type and have an option to hide selected columns and I think you can also reorder the columns.  Changed made here will affect your Edit and Create views.

Comment: yes it worked well, but i did not understand why there is not a view called create or edit, inside the view list from list options. something same as the "All item" view and the  "My issue" view , etc?

Comment: Create and Edit are forms not views.

Comment: A view is a way to display some or all of the items in your list, sorting and filtering them, and controlling which columns are shown. New, Edit and Display show all the columns of a SINGLE item.